# Obtaining rotation field name defined in Labels "Data Defined" section in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

I'm trying to find how to get with the QGIS Python API the layer field name that contain the rotation angle used by a layer to rotate its labels?

I know that I can obtain the field name containing the text used to label features this way:

```
palyr = QgsPalLayerSettings()
palyr.readFromLayer(layer)
f = palyr.fieldName
```

but I can't figure out how to obtain the rotation field name when setted in the "Data defined" section... The QgsPalLayerSettings class contains a lot of methods related to the manipulation of "DataDefined" properties.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Access to the data defined properties was [just fixed today](https://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS/commit/c9c013572fd8b7fc583d5fa7c7721e121274999d) (previously caused a crash). Following your example code, you can access it like so (*most QgsPalLayerSettings properties are accessed directly*):

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
palyr = QgsPalLayerSettings()
palyr.readFromLayer(layer)

# get currently set data definitions as dict of 
#   {QgsPalLayerSettings.DataDefinedProperties: QgsDataDefined}
#   e.g. {18: <qgis.core.QgsDataDefined object at 0x1237daa70>, 10: ...}
ddp = palyr.dataDefinedProperties

# get a data definition from those currently set
ddft = None
if QgsPalLayerSettings.FontTransp in ddp:
    ddft = ddp[QgsPalLayerSettings.FontTransp]

# or try to get a data definition directly (returns None if not found)
ddfc = palyr.dataDefinedProperty(QgsPalLayerSettings.FontCase)
ddfc_field = ''
if ddfc is not None:
    ddfc_field = ddfc.field()


# you can update the data definition as well
ddfc = palyr.dataDefinedProperty(QgsPalLayerSettings.FontCase)
if ddfc:
    ddfc.setField('myfield')  # which would need to be a valid field

# you can also add a new data definition
if not QgsPalLayerSettings.Size in ddp:
    # add an active definition that defines to use an expression of 36 
    # (i.e. no attribute field is mapped)
    palyr.setDataDefinedProperty(QgsPalLayerSettings.Size, True, True, '36', '')

# whenever you update/add/remove a data definition,
# from your QgsPalLayerSettings object, if you want to
# save it to the project instance and see results on canvas
palyr.writeToLayer(layer)
iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

In order to know what `DataDefinedProperties` enums to use, review [the QgsPalLayerSettings docs](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsPalLayerSettings.html). Consult the [docs on QgsDataDefined](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsDataDefined.html) to see how to access/manipulate it.