# Labeling vector features using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, labeling

I am using Python for QGIS 2.0.1 and I have a vector layer of points representing the positions of state labels. I want to display the 'state abbreviation' attribute on the corresponding point for each feature.

Does anyone have an example using QgsPalLabeling to do this?

This is a fairly simple process using the new Labeling tab of the GUI, but I have not found any documentation to make this work programmatically using PyQGIS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just figured this one out thanks to a modification of [an older post by dakcarto](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70111/how-to-obtain-rotation-field-name-defined-in-the-labels-data-defined-section-i).

Basically the python would need to look like this (replace everything in bold):

```
palyr = QgsPalLayerSettings()
palyr.readFromLayer(My Vector Layer)
palyr.enabled = True
palyr.fieldName = 'My Attribute Field Name'
palyr.placement= QgsPalLayerSettings.OverPoint
palyr.setDataDefinedProperty(QgsPalLayerSettings.Size,True,True,'8','')
palyr.writeToLayer(My Vector Layer)
```

Comment: For QGIS 3.x, have a look at here:https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273266/reading-and-setting-label-settings-in-pyqgis-3/273268#273268