# PyQgis create labels

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, labeling, qgis-2.14

I am creating a QgsVectorLayer in a plugin and loading it into the map. I would like to set the labelling parameters while I'm doing that. I've followed several examples found [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77870/how-to-label-vector-features-programmatically) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84723/rendering-and-labeling-shapefile-with-pyqgis?lq=1), but my labels aren't being displayed. When I go to the labelling tool none of the settings are as I've specified.

```
def finalize(self):
    self.vl.commitChanges()
    self.vl.updateExtents()
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(self.vl)
    self.setDisplayProperties()


def setDisplayProperties(self):
    palyr = QgsPalLayerSettings()
    palyr.readFromLayer(self.vl)
    palyr.enabled = True       #this works
    palyr.fieldName = 'label'  #this works
    palyr.placement = QgsPalLayerSettings.OverPoint  #??
    palyr.placementFlags = palyr.placementFlags or QgsPalLayerSettings(BelowLine)    # not working
    palyr.fontSizeInMapUnits = False
    palyr.textFont.setPointSize(4.6)  #results in 4 - seems to be integer only
    palyr.textColor = QColor(68,92,249) #this works
    palyr.writeToLayer(self.vl)
```

I've tried calling setDisplayProperties at every slot in the finalize procedure with the same result every time.  I've also tried with and without various settings.

Comment: Do you receive any errors from the Python Console when you run the above code? Also, you're labelling `layer` but you're adding `vl` to the canvas. Are they meant to be different?

Comment: @Joseph good pick, but changing it to vl only had partial improvements marked above. There are no Python errors

Comment: For future readers, Joseph and @artwork21 found typos in my code. I've incorporated their changes above, which is now a working example.

Answer (score 1):

The "c" in `textcolor` needs to be upper case like:

```
palyr.textColor = QColor(68,92,249)
```