# Reading and setting label settings in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, labeling, qgis-3

In QGIS 2.18 I read and set label style settings like this:

```
props = {
    "labeling": "pal",
    "labeling/enabled": "true",
    "labeling/fontFamily": "Arial",
    "labeling/fontSize": "12",
    "labeling/fieldName": "Name",
    "labeling/bufferDraw": True,
    "labeling/bufferSize": "1",
    "labeling/bufferColor": "white"
    }
for k, v in props.items():
    my_layer.setCustomProperty(k, v)
```

How do I do the equivalent in QGIS 3.0?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found the answer for QGIS 3.0:

```
layer_settings  = QgsPalLayerSettings()
text_format = QgsTextFormat()

text_format.setFont(QFont("Arial", 12))
text_format.setSize(12)

buffer_settings = QgsTextBufferSettings()
buffer_settings.setEnabled(True)
buffer_settings.setSize(1)
buffer_settings.setColor(QColor("white"))

text_format.setBuffer(buffer_settings)
layer_settings.setFormat(text_format)

layer_settings.fieldName = "my_attribute"
layer_settings.placement = 2

layer_settings.enabled = True

layer_settings = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(layer_settings)
my_layer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
my_layer.setLabeling(layer_settings)
my_layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Comment: For those like me, who want to use it with expression: layer_settings.fieldName = "your_expression_here" / layer_settings.isExpression = True

Comment: Nice comment, my only problem is after running this all the settings ha been updated. but on line features I need to click on the properties an click apply for the changes to be noticeable in the map. Is there a way to force the apply function programatically?