# Setting label settings in PyQGIS 3 to mapUnits?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, labeling, map-unit

I am converting several Plugins from QGIS 3 and I am struggling heavily with symbology and labeling. The straightforwart QGIS 2 approach seems to be totally gone. I found some help here:

[Reading and setting label settings in PyQGIS 3?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273266/reading-and-setting-label-settings-in-pyqgis-3/301813#301813)

But I can't figure out how to set the label-size to map Units, the QGIS2 approach was:

```
layer_loaded.setCustomProperty("labeling/fontFamily", "Arial")
layer_loaded.setCustomProperty("labeling/fontSize", "100")
layer_loaded.setCustomProperty("labeling/fontSizeInMapUnits", "true")
```

The new approach seems to be

```
layer_settings  = QgsPalLayerSettings()
text_format = QgsTextFormat()

text_format.setFont(QFont("Arial", 10))
text_format.setSize(100)
text_format.setSizeMapUnitScale(True) <-- wants a "QgsMapUnitScale"

layer_settings.setFormat(text_format)

layer_settings = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(layer_settings)
layer_loaded.setLabeling(layer_settings)
```

Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call

```
textFormat.setSizeUnit(QgsUnitTypes.RenderMapUnits)
```

(see https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/core/Text/QgsTextFormat.html#qgis.core.QgsTextFormat.setSizeUnit)

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm and improved my unterstanding of the documentation. (So text_format.setSizeMapUnitScale(QgsMapUnitScale) was completely unnecessary.)

Comment: Yes, that's only necessary to set the map unit size limits.

Comment: Do you know how to change to MapUnits in the symbology of lines as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```py
QgsTextFormat().setSizeUnit(QgsUnitTypes.RenderMapUnits) 
QgsTextFormat().setSize(100)
```

Also you can use one of this others render units instead of `RenderMapUnits`:
`RenderMillimeters`, `RenderPixels`, `RenderPercentage`, `RenderPoints`, `RenderInches`, `RenderUnknownUnit`, and `RenderMetersInMapUnits`.

Documentation: https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsUnitTypes.html