# Iterating through QgsFeatures in active layer and adding label using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, labeling, vector, linestring

I am trying to plot contours that are stored in a shapefile (linestrings) with labels that have their value.  I know how to get the feature attribute I want in Python via:

```
name = "MSLP"
layer = QgsVectorLayer(path_to_file,name,"ogr")
idx = layer.fields().indexFromName(name)

for feat in layer.getFeatures():

     attr = feat.attributes()[idx]
```

However, I'm not sure how to set a label to the feature.  I've looked at the QgsPalLabeling class but I don't see any examples on how to do this iteratively, and many examples are using QGIS 2.x (I'm using 3.x).  I might create a separate file with points along each polyline per value, assign the value, and override the default symbol as a string, if possible.  But I'm open to a different solution, especially if it means fewer I/O and one less shapefile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [Reading and setting label settings in PyQGIS 3?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273266/reading-and-setting-label-settings-in-pyqgis-3) It has the options for version 3 (and 2) and seems complete.

**-edit-**

**vl** is a *QgsVectorLayer* in the code below. Definitely works, even the curved styling to follow a curved feature.

1. **layer_settings.enabled** has been commented out. It prevented curved labels
2. using **layer_settings.placementFlags = QgsLabeling.OnLine** puts the labels on top of the lines rather than above or below them.
3. **layer_settings.fieldName = "TURNID"** - where the labels come from

   ```
    layer_settings = QgsPalLayerSettings()

    buffer_settings = QgsTextBufferSettings()
    buffer_settings.setEnabled(True)
    buffer_settings.setSize(1)
    buffer_settings.setColor(QColor("white"))

    text_format = QgsTextFormat()
    text_format.setFont(QFont("Arial", 6))
    text_format.setSize(6)

    text_format.setBuffer(buffer_settings)
    layer_settings.setFormat(text_format)

    layer_settings.fieldName = "TURNID"
    layer_settings.placement = QgsPalLayerSettings.Curved
    layer_settings.placementFlags = QgsLabeling.OnLine
    # layer_settings.enabled = False
    layer_settings = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(layer_settings)

    vl.setLabelsEnabled(True)
    vl.setLabeling(layer_settings)
   ```

Comment: Labels do not show up using that, no

Comment: Added some code that definitely works (see above). What have you actually tried?

Comment: I think I was using API that was a little newer than my version of QGIS.  I changed a few lines in yours (ex: QgsLabeling is 3.12+) and got it to work.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes,  there appear to have been some recent changes. **placement** and **placementFlags** seem similar, but one seems to control location and the other orientation.