# How to add labelling to a polygon layer?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I'm trying to add labelling to a polygons vector layer called "myVectorLayer" with the following code:

```
palyr = QgsPalLayerSettings()
palyr.readFromLayer(myVectorLayer)

palyr.enabled = True
palyr.fieldName = 'name'
palyr.placement= QgsPalLayerSettings.OverPoint
palyr.setDataDefinedProperty(QgsPalLayerSettings.Size,True,True,'8','')

palyr.writeToLayer(myVectorLayer)
```

It does not give me any error but the labelling does not appear. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [How to obtain rotation field name defined in the Labels "Data Defined" section in pyqgis?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70111). You will need to refresh the map canvas at the end of your code to see changes.

You are setting the `palyr.fieldName` to 'name,' which will need to be a valid attribute table field. Please verify.

You mention adding the labeling settings to "myVectorLayer." The [`QgsPalLayerSettings().readFromLayer(vlayer)` function](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsPalLayerSettings.html#ac4b2c35cf755ef8ea4edfb7beb5d992a) needs a [QgsVectorLayer](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html) for its parameter. It is unclear whether your "myVectorLayer" (in your code) is a QgsVectorLayer instance, or just the textual name of the layer. If it is the latter, you will need to query `QgsMapLayerRegistry` to find its QgsMapLayer instance:

```
QList<QgsMapLayer *> QgsMapLayerRegistry::mapLayersByName(QString layerName)
```

Comment: yes indeed I am wrong in writing "Fieldname". thank you very muth