# Connecting vector label size with map-units?

Tags: pyqgis, labeling, qgis-2, font, map-unit

I have a working application of labels to a point array - but the size of the text is not relative to the map scale.  This decreases the readability of labels when panning and zooming.

To resolve~

How would one implement a text-size based on MapUnits?

```
    field = str(csvGridFieldNames[index])
    csvGrid = ftools_utils.getMapLayerByName(unicode('mfLayer1_Grid'))#str(activeLayer)))
    textSize = 7
    valLabel = QgsPalLayerSettings()
    valLabel.readFromLayer(csvGrid)
    valLabel.enabled = True
    valLabel.fieldName = field
    valLabel.placement= QgsPalLayerSettings.OverPoint
    valLabel.setDataDefinedProperty(QgsPalLayerSettings.Size,True,True,'%f' %(textSize),'')
    valLabel.writeToLayer(csvGrid)
    iface.legendInterface().refreshLayerSymbology(csvGrid)
    iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

This question appears related, but having some trouble understanding the doc's...

["...lables 'Data Defined' section in pyqgis"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70111/how-to-obtain-rotation-field-name-defined-in-the-labels-data-defined-section-i)

...and FWIW:

A screen shot of the Qgis tool, with the two (needed) PyQgis settable parameters highlighted in green:
[image: lable settings]

**Updates following underdark's advice:**

Input syntax errors (on my part) are not raising error flags - but are also not implementing MapUnit based font/label size...

```
    valLabel.SizeUnit = QgsPalLayerSettings.MapUnits
    valLabel.setDataDefinedProperty(QgsPalLayerSettings.FontSizeUnit,True,True,':%f' %(textSize),'')
```

**LAST UPDATE [SOLVED]**
(final working code below):

```
    textSize = (abs(scale[0]-scale[1]))/4
    valLabel = QgsPalLayerSettings()
    valLabel.readFromLayer(csvGrid)
    valLabel.enabled = True
    valLabel.fontSizeInMapUnits = True
    valLabel.fieldName = field
    valLabel.placement = QgsPalLayerSettings.OverPoint
    valLabel.setDataDefinedProperty(QgsPalLayerSettings.Size,True,True,'%f' %(textSize),'')
    valLabel.writeToLayer(csvGrid)
    iface.legendInterface().refreshLayerSymbology(csvGrid)
    iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me:

```
valLabel=QgsPalLayerSettings()
valLabel.readFromLayer(iface.activeLayer())
valLabel.fontSizeInMapUnits=True // change to map units
valLabel.textFont.setPointSize(100000) // set font size
valLabel.writeToLayer(iface.activeLayer())
iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

---

For the data-defined way check [QgsPalLayerSettings::DataDefinedProperties
FontSizeUnit](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsPalLayerSettings.html#aa4a68d8eea503219523ce0c7f0ba3ceaa7825f9191edeb5245e5589f768616cb1)

and [enum QgsPalLayerSettings::SizeUnit](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsPalLayerSettings.html#a6a79cd114865439dd9a4668abd927597)

> Units used for option sizes, before being converted to rendered sizes.
>
> Enumerator
>
> Points
> MM
> MapUnits
> Percent

Comment: Thank you underdark!  Added some edits per your advice.  Although, it seems syntax errors might be present - as desired effect is not implaced.

Comment: Wow - way simpler than I was making things to be. This seems right 'valLabel.fontSizeInMapUnits=True' although having secondary problems setting actual measure.  Thanks for speedy wisdom from that side of the pond!

Comment: COMMENT REMOVED:  figured it out, the data-defined 'size' is still used following the advice you gave.  Thanks'again

Comment: "valLabel.textFont.setPointSize(100000) // set font size
"   Even simpler than the working implemented data-defined method I had. Nice Crown!

Comment: For some reason, my variable 'textSize' doesn't scale properly when using the setPointSize() method.  Ergo - if I change the 'scale' distance [textSize = (abs(scale[0]-scale[1]))/4], the text becomes oversized.  Yet if I stick with the data-defined means, scale is maintained. Not to sure at the moment why this is the case - but figured it might be useful for others if they have a variable input setting their font size.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. If you want, open a new thread and explain what you want to achieve with this scale construct.

Comment: I feel bad to flood the boards - so I will try to be succinct here.  I have a equidistant point array, where 'scale' is =to the distance between points.  The user inputs a value for this distance when the array is created.  Which is retrieved and resized via 'textSize = (abs(scale[0]-scale[1]))/4' to assure each point's label text does not overlap neighboring labels.   The data-defined method maintains this scale appropriately whilst the user makes changes to the inter-point distance, but I could not get the setPointSize() method to fulfill this same need.