# Adding label to QgsVectorLayer in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, labeling, layers

My goal  is to define labels programmatically for the case similar for the figure below:

[image: labelling layer manually using QGIS UI]

But I didn't find any guidance how to do so using Python.

I have a feeling it could be done using QgsLabel but didn't find any working exmaple how to do so.

I seek some example how to do so;

If I'm wrong with QgsLabel idea, can you explain briefly the right approach for this?

As usual some code example could be very useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Activate your layer in the ToC and try this in the QGIS Python console:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling", "pal")
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/enabled", "true")
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/fontFamily", "Arial")
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/fontSize", "10")
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/fieldName", "ename")
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/placement", "2")
iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

---

An alternate way would be to use `QgsPalLayerSettings()`, like in [MultiLine field-name label referencing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132905/multiline-field-name-label-referencing?lq=1), however, it didn't work for me in QGIS v.2.8.

*By the way, next time try [this kind of search](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=[pyqgis]%20label%20vector).*

Comment: this is a great update on labeling conjecture.  Been unable to use the palLayersettings since the 2.8 update. Is there documentation for the new programmatic application?

Comment: @Katalpa Not that I'm aware of.