# Pythonic solution for changing shapefiles properties in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python

I'm loading several shapefiles into QGIS using the Python console. The script works by reading a list of directories and a list of shapefiles to load from each directory, then it loads each file. Like this:

```
encList = "/foo/encList.txt"
shapeList = "/foo/shpList.txt"
path = "/bar/"
with open(encList) as encs:
    for enc in encs:
            with open(shapeList) as shps:
                    for shp in shps:
                            file=path+str(enc).rstrip()+'/'+str(enc).rstrip()+str(shp).rstrip()+".shp"
                            print file
                            qgis.utils.iface.addVectorLayer(file, str(enc).rstrip()+str(shp).rstrip(), 'ogr' )

                            #Use loaded layer as active layer to set the CRS
                            myLayer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
                            myLayer.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.EpsgCrsId))
```

I would like to also configure the shapefile layers as I go along. As you would if you right click on a layer and select properties.

Specifically, I would like to change the line colours and label display. In my head I'd need something like this pseudo-code added into the loop:

```
if shapefile == line:
   then shapefile.setColor(black)
if shapefile == points:
   then shapefile.setStyle(pointDisplacement)
   ans shapefile.setStyle.lable('nameOfPoint')
```

Or something like that. I have figured out how to do the conditions, I just need to understand how to change the attributes. Does anybody know of a way or a tutorial?

(I'm new to QGIS, but know my way around Python)

Comment: You can have a look at [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70058/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-vector-layer-in-pyqgis) about PyQgis color settings. There is a more detailed tuto [here](http://snorf.net/blog/2014/03/04/symbology-of-vector-layers-in-qgis-python-plugins/) about general styling.

Comment: Further more, you can check this question for labels: [How to add label to QgsVectorLayer by Python](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136526/how-to-add-label-to-qgsvectorlayer-by-python).

Comment: Also I would suggest to familiarize yourself with pyqgis api, and data model. That would make your life easier in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some tinkering and reading up on the most helpful comments I've managed do solve this, mostly with the help of [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70058/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-vector-layer-in-pyqgis) (thanks arMoraer) and reading some of the reference material.

I would recommend reading [this tutorial](http://snorf.net/blog/2014/03/04/symbology-of-vector-layers-in-qgis-python-plugins/) (again thanks arMoraer) which gives a little bit of information into the data structure of layers.

Here is a copy of the completed "loader" code with the conditional colour changes:

```
encList = "/foo/encList.txt"
shapeList = "/foo/shpList.txt"
path = "/bar/"
with open(encList) as encs:
    for enc in encs:
            with open(shapeList) as shps:
                    for shp in shps:
                            file=path+str(enc).rstrip()+'/'+str(enc).rstrip()+str(shp).rstrip()+".shp"
                            print file
                            qgis.utils.iface.addVectorLayer(file, str(enc).rstrip()+str(shp).rstrip(), 'ogr' )

                            #Use loaded layer as active layer and set the CRS
                            layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
                            layer.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.EpsgCrsId))

                            # If the shape is designated as a line type
                            if(str(shp).rstrip()[-1:] == "L"):
                                symbols = layer.rendererV2().symbols()
                                symbol = symbols[0]
                                symbol.setColor(QtGui.QColor.fromRgb(0,0,0))

                            # If the shape is designated as a point type
                            if(str(shp).rstrip()[-1:] == "P"):
                                symbols = layer.rendererV2().symbols()
                                symbol = symbols[0]
                                symbol.setColor(QtGui.QColor.fromRgb(255, 77, 77))

                            qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().refresh() 
                            qgis.utils.iface.legendInterface().refreshLayerSymbology(layer)
```

Maybe this will help out a fellow newbie who got waist deep in QGIS as quickly as I did. Thank you to all of those who added comments and guidance.