# Multi-line labeling of a shapefile layer with pyQGis

Tags: pyqgis, labeling

I want to label a shp layer on two lines with pyQGis.
I managed to do it with only one field, but with two or more fields (using concat) it does not work anymore.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
def labelLine (lyr, fieldNom1, fieldNom2):
  # This function shows the labels of 2 fields "fieldName1" and "fieldName2" for a Line layer lyr
  label = QgsPalLayerSettings ()
  label.readFromLayer (lyr)
  label.enabled = True
  # we concatenate the two fields
  label.fieldName = "concat ('BASE:', fieldName1, '\\ n', 'L =', fieldName2, 'm')"
  label.placement = QgsPalLayerSettings.Line
  label.bufferDraw = True
  label.bufferSize = 1
  label.setDataDefinedProperty (QgsPalLayerSettings.S ize, True, True, '8', '')
  label.writeToLayer (lyr)
```

Comment: Maybe try replacing `\\ n` with `\n`? So `label.fieldName = "concat('BASE:', fieldName1, '\n', 'L =', fieldName2, 'm')"`.

Comment: Thank you, I tried your proposal but it did not work.

Comment: What happens when you use it? Is it still on a single line? Is there an error in the expression? Maybe you can post a screenshot of how the label looks?

Comment: - With one field, it works very well:
label.fieldName = champNom1
The label, in this case it is the length of each segment of an electric line, appears correctly.
 
- With the concat expression, there is no error after the code compilation but there is no label  on the line segments.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132905/multiline-field-name-label-referencing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps try something like the following expression. We can use the `to_string` function from the **Field Calculator** to convert any value from a field to a string (as you can't concatenate strings and values):

```
'''concat('BASE: ' + to_string("''' + fieldName1 + '''"),'\nL = ' + to_string("''' + fieldName2 + '''") + 'm')'''
```

---

So your code could look like:

```
def labelLine(lyr, fieldName1, fieldName2):
    label = QgsPalLayerSettings()
    label.readFromLayer(lyr)
    label.enabled = True
    label.fieldName = '''concat('BASE: ' + to_string("''' + fieldName1 + '''"),'\nL = ' + to_string("''' + fieldName2 + '''") + 'm')'''
    label.placement = QgsPalLayerSettings.Line
    label.bufferDraw = True
    label.bufferSize = 1
    label.setDataDefinedProperty(QgsPalLayerSettings.Size, True, True, '8', '')
    label.writeToLayer(lyr)
    lyr.setCustomProperty("labeling/drawLabels", True)
    lyr.triggerRepaint()

lyr = iface.activeLayer()
labelLine(lyr, 'fieldName1', 'fieldName2')
```

Example:

[image: Example]

Comment: Many thanks Joseph for your very helpful code. 
However, the label do not appear automatically in QGis and I have to switch the Layer Properties/Labels, and toggle OK.
I try to add the following to confirm the changes but it does not work:
layer.triggerRepaint()
or 
layer.commitChanges()
layer.updateExtents()
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @ennine - Most welcome! Edited the post to include additional lines of code which should _hopefully_ enable and draw the labels :)

Comment: see this link: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/259369/multi-field-labelling-of-a-shape-file-with-pyqgis

Comment: @ennine - Did you see my edit and test the two lines of code I added? I don't see them in the question you posted :)

Comment: Unfortunatly, I tried the two last lines of the code, but it did not work

Comment: @ennine - This worked for me previously on QGIS 2.18.2. I recently updated to 2.18.13 and now it doesn't work. I wonder if this is a bug...

Comment: I tried QGIS LTR 2.14.19 with no result.

Answer (score 3):

What about using the `wrapChar()` method of QgsPalLayerSettings (http://qgis.org/api/2.18/classQgsPalLayerSettings.html)
You can set a character that is intended to wrap the label string

something like:

```
label.wrapChar = '*'
```

and then in your code:

```
label.fieldName = "concat ('BASE:', fieldName1, '*', 'L =', fieldName2, 'm')"
```

then run, it may work

Comment: Unfortunetly, after the code compilation, I received the following error:

Comment: label. WrapChar('*')
AttributeError: 'QgsPalLayerSettings' object has no attribute 'WrapChar'

Comment: Remove the upper W and replace with lower w

Comment: When I replace WrapChar by wrapChar, I receive the following error: label. wrapChar('*')
TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable

Comment: if you do a copy/paste of the error, you have a space between the dot and `wrapChar`... remove it.

Comment: Ok, my fault, please see my edited answer and try with it. `label.wrapChar = '*'` I test it and it work!

Comment: Now, I have no error after the code compilation, but still the labels do not appear in QGis. However, when I investigate the property layer/Labelling, I notice that the expression is as follows: concat ('BASE:', fieldName1, '*', 'L =', fieldName2, 'm'). It seems that fieldName1 & fieldName2 are not recognised as fields.

Comment: Can you provide the whole code you use?

Comment: You kindly find below the written code (comments are written in french):

Comment: Sorry, I can not transmit the code because it is too long.

Comment: Edit your question With the updated code

Comment: I try to attach the code but it seems that I exceeded the size limit of sending

Comment: Attach it in the question, not in the comment. How long is it??